# Поменять местами строки и столбцы в двумерном массиве с помощью дополнительного вектора

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть двумерный массив, количество столбцов и рядов указывает пользователь, задача в том чтобы поменять местами 2 столбец с 3-им рядом используя дополнительный вектор

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 100
#define M 100
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int rows = 0, columns = 0;
    cout << "Введите количество строк массива: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов массива: ";
    cin >> columns;

    int Array[N][M];
    cout << "Начальный массив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            Array[i][j] = rand() % 41 - 20;
            cout << Array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    cout << endl;

    //Нужен дополнительный вектор, а это попытка выполнить задание без вектора
    for (int i = 0; i < rows && i < columns; i++)
    {
        int tmp;
        tmp = Array[3][i];
        Array[3][i] = Array[i][2];
        Array[i][2] = tmp;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Преобразованный массив: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (rows == 3 || columns == 2) {
            cout << "Вы ввели слишком маленькое значение" << endl;
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << Array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Покажите, каких успехов в решении задачи вы добились сами.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы верно решили задачу. Т.к. строгого решения у этой задачи в общем случае быть не может, если действительно надо поменять именно 2-й СТОЛБЕЦ с 3-м РЯДОМ.

Рассмотрим случаи:

1. Допустим ввели число рядов N не равное числу столбцов M. Как тогда поменять столбец со строкой? У них же разное число элементов, следовательно их просто так поменять как есть целиком невозможно. Только если поменять число MIN(N, M) первых элементов. Т.е. уже задача строго не может быть решена в этом случае.
2. Допустим ввели число рядов и столбцов одинаковое число, т.е. матрица квадратная. В этом случае возникает вопрос, что делать в точке пересечения обмениваемых ряда и столбца. С одной стороны в точке пересечения в новом ряду 2-м элементом должен идти 2-й элемент старого столбца, с другой стороны в той же точке пересечения 3-й элемент нового столбца должен быть равен 3-му элементу старого ряда. Но 2-й элемент старого столбца и 3-й элемент старого ряда это разные элементы. Получается противоречие, что в одной точке пересечения должны быть одновременно два разных элемента. Т.е. для случая когда обмениваем ряд и столбец с разными номерами решения строгого нет.

Итого, задача строго разрешима только если число столбцов и рядов равно плюс обмениваются столбец и ряд с одинаковым номером. Либо может быть в задаче опечатка и нужно поменять 2-й столбец с 3-м также столбцом. Иначе задачу можно решить только приблизительно. Как вы и решили, у вас большинство элементов правильно обменено, за исключением одного-двух элементов.